# Get XML parent tag with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, xml

I know regular expressions are not exactly the best way to extract info out of an XML file, but in this case it's better for me to use regular expressions because in the structure of my program they are also used to extract information out of different types of files (text, program code etc.)

Let's say we have the following XML code:

```
<modules>
    <Orba_Sheepla>
        <!-- module version -->
        <version>0.9.25</version>
    </Orba_Sheepla>
</modules>
```

What I need is the "Orba_Sheepla" in this case. What I need in general is the **tag one level above the `<version>` tag** (i.e. the parent tag). It is possible that there are other tags before and after the  tag on the same level. I need to make sure that the tag (or rather: the name of the tag) containing the `<version>` tag is found.

I have tried different kinds of regular expressions, but I can't seem to write the right one. Can I somehow tell the expressions to match "TAG ABC" the following?

```
<TAG ABC>
    anything
    <version>anything</version>
    anything
</THE VERY SAME TAG ABC>
```

Of course, other solutions are just as welcome!

Comment: So, in XML language, you need to get the version node parent tag name, right? With XML parser, it would be really easy.

Comment: Yes, I need the parent tag, and yes, it would be really easy with a parser. I can't use a parser here, though, without changes the structure of my program in order to match this specific case.

Comment: can you please show what you have tried. lots of love

Comment: The regex solution will be inefficient, too unreadable or too "fragile". No, I doubt anyone will be able to correctly answer your question. Use XML parser, it is a forward-looking solution. Imagine you need to get other similar values, then, you will already have a highly customizable solution. Either add a programming language tag, or the question should be closed.

Comment: This is the closest to a solution that still worked: '<modules>\\s+<(.+?)>\\s+<version>.+</version>' But of course this only takes whitespaces into account, not additional tags or comments. When I replace \\s+ with .+?, though, it stops returning matches and I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: @stribizhev I have added "python" to the tags. And I know this is not exactly a beautiful solution to this problem, but in this case there is no beautiful solution. I might eventually rework the entire structure of my code, but I'd like to at least find something that works first.

Comment: Though, if there are no robust and working regex solutions that are not totally bloated, I really should consider including an extra case for this specific issue. I certainly don't want to stick to regexs if they don't provide a solid solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **tag one level above** the `<version>`
>   it's better for me to use regular expressions
>   I can't use a parser here

**You should use an XML parser!** It's easier, more robust and it shouldn't involve a great effort refactoring. Use `lxml` where you have the `getparent()` function and XPath 1.0 is fully implemented.
<sup>Thanks to stribizhev for recommending this should be remarked</sup>

Anyway, here's a workaround that will work for the most simple cases (and will fail in many real-life examples).

- If, and only if, your XML is properly indented, you could capture the next closing tag with a lower indentation level.

**Regex:**

```
(?smi)^([ \t]+)<version>.*?^(?!\1)[ \t]*</([^\s>]+)
```

Captures the closing tag in group 2.
What it does is:

- <kbd>`^([ \t]+)`</kbd> It captures the spaces before
- <kbd>`<version>`</kbd> the tag you want
- <kbd>`.*?^`</kbd> then it finds the next line
- <kbd>`(?!\1)[ \t]*`</kbd> with less indentation
- <kbd>`</([^\s>]+)`</kbd> and captures the closing tag

**Code:**

```python
import re

text = '''
<modules>
    <Orba_Sheepla>
        <!-- module version -->
        <version>0.9.25</version>
    </Orba_Sheepla>
</modules>'''

pattern = re.compile( r'^([ \t]+)<version>.*?^(?!\1)[ \t]*</([^\s>]+)', re.I | re.S | re.M)
match = pattern.search(text)

if match:
    print(match.group(2))
```

**Output:**

```
Orba_Sheepla
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vN6gW6/1)</kbd> <kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/NhTuTp)</kbd>

Comment: Just a note: in this workaround, it is assumed your XML is properly indented. These assumptions multiply in real life. Use `lxml` where you have `getparent()` function and XPath 1.0 is fully implemented. I have been downvoted highly for such workarounds.

Comment: Indeed, it's a cheap workaround. I thought that was clear enough, though I've just added the remark to the answer.